# How to use strpos to find words inside link

Tags: php

I'm going create database table `badwords` to store some unwanted words [`id,word`] as following.

```
CREATE TABLE `badwords`(
`id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`word` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id` (`id`))
```

let say i've stored the following words

```
(1,ugly)
(2,yak)
```

Now my visitors might post some links contains one of those bad words and i'm willing to use something like this.

```
$user = "http://www.this_ugly_site.com"; // visitor post this (ugly) word within

// i'm gonna try to find any of bad words stored in my table

$qry="select * from badwords where word='$user'"; // how to do it (find)
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die($qry);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)=='0'){

echo "Good URL";

}else{

while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "Bad URL";

}}
```

I do not know how to apply `strpos` and if it really good solution or there is something else i can use !

or can i use

```
$qry="select * from badwords where word LIKE '%$user%'";
```

but it looks un-secure as it embedded a user-provided value into your SQL

so any idea or help how to do it ~ thanks

Comment: Be careful with this. I'm almost certain you'll want to block `sex`, but you probably won't want to block, for example, `theessextimes.com`, which any `strpos()`-based approach almost certainly will. Also, take a look at the [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) MySQL operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked 3 separate questions:

1. **How do I use `strpos()`**

   It's a native PHP function that takes three parameters. I'd encourage you to use and learn the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/strpos). Nonetheless, here is an example:

   ```
   strpos($string, $bad_word);
   ```
2. **Is there a better way?**

   Likely. But what you have isn't bad. `strpos()` is one of the faster string functions. If you had thousands of *bad words* and a large amount of requests per second, then you'd likely want to look into caching the *bad words* instead of querying MySQL every time. However, no need to prematurely optimize. For now, fail early. That is when you find a *bad word*, `break` out of the loop.
3. **How do you escape a string in MySQL?**

   I'd encourage you to use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension and then [`mysqli->real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

   For example:

   ```
   $qry = "SELECT * FROM badwords WHERE word LIKE '%" . $dbc->real_escape_string($user) . "%'";
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on doing something like this, I would have MySQL do all the work for you. What you need to do is reverse the order of the operands to the way you are probably used to using them in a `LIKE` clause:

```
SELECT `word`
FROM `badwords`
WHERE '<user_input>' LIKE concat('%', `word`, '%')
LIMIT 1
```

The basic PHP code would be something like:

```
// User input
$user = "http://www.this_ugly_site.com";

// Find matching words
// Do NOT show mysql_error() or $query in a production environment!
$query = "
  SELECT `word`
  FROM `badwords`
  WHERE '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."' LIKE concat('%', `word`,'%')
  LIMIT 1
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error()."\n".$query);

// Test for a match
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "Bad URL (matches {$row['word']})";
} else {
  echo "Good URL";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're searching for your string backwards.  I'm not sure that I'd use MySQL to do this; instead I might pull all the bad words out of the table, and search my string, like this:

```
<?
$user_string = "http://www.this_ugly_site.com";

$query = "SELECT word FROM badwords";
$res = mysql_query($query);

$stringOkay = true;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    //use stripos for case insensitive matching
    if (stripos($user_string, $row['word']) !== false)
    {
        //this user string contains a bad word!
        $stringOkay = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($stringOkay) echo "Good URL";
else echo "Bad URL";
```

As DaveRandom commented in your OP, you're going to come up with *a lot* of false positives, and false negatives, using this method of searching.  a slightly better way is to use regular expressions, but even those aren't fool proof.

For example, you might want to block the word 'yak' bot not 'kayak' so to accomplish this, you'd use regular expressions with word delineators (\b) and you'd have an expression like this: `#(^|\b)yak(\b|$)#i`, this also affords you to block stuff like "ass" when spelled in "leet speak" with a pattern like this `#a(55|$$)#i` but again, this is subject to false negatives, as someone could type `a5$` or `a**`.  Basically, this is a "hard problem" and you're going to need a more complex solution to get complete coverage/protection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = "http://www.this_ugly_site.com"; 
$qry="select word_column_name from badwords"; 
$badwords=mysql_query($qry);
if(badword($user,$badwords))
    echo "bad url";

function badword($user,$badwords)
{    
   foreach($badwords as $badword)
   {
     if(stristr($text,$badword))
     {
            return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```